# Morris.js on node.js not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, morris.js

Im trying to use morris.js on my web, on the official web they have a simple example: [morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) I followed, installing packages with npm but, on my html Morris dont found and I dont get any error from console, just don't see nothing, Anyone know what might be happening? I'm using node.js 0.10 and that its my code:

(Im using a Single Page Application)

**index.html**

...

```
    <!-- Morris.js -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/morris.js/morris.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/morris.js/morris.js"></script>

    ...
    <body>      
        <div data-ng-view>
        </div>                      
    </body>
    ...
```

**page.html**

```
       <div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>

        <script>
            new Morris.Line({
                // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
                element: 'myfirstchart',
                // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
                // the chart.
                data: [
                    { year: '2008', value: 20 },
                    { year: '2009', value: 10 },
                    { year: '2010', value: 5 },
                    { year: '2011', value: 5 },
                    { year: '2012', value: 20 }
                ],
                // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
                xkey: 'year',
                // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
                ykeys: ['value'],
                // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
                // chart.
                labels: ['Value']
            });
        </script>
```

**node_modules on my proyect**

[image: node_modules on my proyect]

And the result on my page its a white space.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that you don't need to instantiate the Morris.Line, you should use

`Morris.Line({element: 'myfirstchart'...})`

See this: http://jsbin.com/uqawig/441/embed?js,output